# Performance on laptops running very slow

Tags: performance

Hi I am running a duel boot win 7 and Ubuntu 13 32bit on a hp pavilion i7 1.6Ghz cpu and 6 gig ram and ati graphics, I have in the past run other Ubuntu’s and even Linux operating systems and all of them run very slow.

I also have a old Siemens laptop with a 1.8 Ghz cpu 1gig ram ati graphics and I am running xubuntu 32bit and that to runs very slow, is there any whay someone can help me.

I have done all the checks on the swap disk usage ect...

Comment: Can you elaborate on the checks you have done so far...some data would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using all of your available RAM. The Ubuntu 64-bit version (the amd64 ISO) is recommended for all computers that have more than 2GB of RAM because it runs faster than the 32-bit version. You should replace your 32-bit Ubuntu install with the 64-bit version.